# AWS CPANEL WHM - IP Address and DNS Settings on new accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, cpanel, whm

I've (hopefully) successfully set up Cpanel on AWS with clustering following the instructions: https://blog.cpanel.com/part-1-how-i-built-a-cpanel-hosting-environment-on-amazon-aws/

I've been using CPanel/WHM on a dedicated server for a few years before I set up this new Cpanel installation on AWS. My issues comes from how new accounts are set up differently on a dedicated server vs the AWS way.

---

**My first issue:**

When I created a new account on my dedicated WHM, I was provided IP Addresses from the server farm that I assigned to newly created accounts. Once assigned, I can access the site with either the IP or the domain name. Now with this new AWS way, there's no info in the tutorials about how I obtain new IP Addresses. I tried adding a new local IP like 10.0.0.30 (because it says it's in NAT mode and use local IP) and assigning this as a dedicated IP to the newly created accounts but I don't understand how anybody can access the site through that IP since its a local IP. So how do I access the domain through custom IP and domain like I did before? I must be missing something fundamental.

---

**My second issue:**

On my dedicated WHM after I created a new account, I would typically go to DNS Functions -> Edit DNS Zone and edit the zone to customize my nameserver as so:

`mynewdomain.com
ns1.mynewdomain.com 
ns2.mynewdomain.com`

`anothersite.com
ns1.anothersite.com
ns2.anothersite.com`

`thirdsite.com
ns1.thirdsite.com
ns2.thirdsite.com`

and then in my register I would add these custom nameservers into the register and point them to the dedicated IPs of each domain. But with the AWS way, the only way I was able to set this up was to use the new cluster nameservers as the nameserver for **ALL** accounts in this new WHM installation.

Like this:

`mynewdomain.com
ns1.awsnameserver.com
ns2.awsnameserver.com`

`anothersite.com
ns1.awsnameserver.com
ns2.awsnameserver.com`

`thirdsite.com
ns1.awsnameserver.com
ns2.awsnameserver.com`

Is this the correct / the only way I can set up accounts now through this set up?
Is there a way to have custom nameservers names like I did in dedicated WHM?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a DNS server outside of Amazon so I'm not sure it would answer your question but it might lead you somewhere.

First to figure out what your public IP is you can:

1. Go to the AWS console and look at the instance detail of your server.
2. Look for the "endpoint".  This points to your public address so you can do a PING or NSLOOKUP to find out what your IP is.

However, AWS does not recommend you hard-coding the public address as it could change.  So what I did instead was to create a CNAME in my DNS that points to that "endpoint".

I hope that helps.